# How to find differing columns for two rows of data in Perl

Tags: perl

I have data like this with 6 columns

```
LINES XY1  XY2  XY3  XY4  XY5
P1    Z/Z  T/T  -/-  T/T  T/T
P2    A/A  A/A  G/G  Z/Z  T/T
1     G/G  T/T  G/G  T/T  G/G
2     T/T  A/A  C/C  C/C  T/T
3     T/T  G/G  T/T  G/G  T/T
4     A/A  C/C  A/A  A/A  A/A
5     A/A  A/A  T/T  T/T  A/A
```

1. I want to find which columns (from `XY1` to `XY5`) are different for rows `P1` and `P2`. Equal means that `P1` and `P2` contain same same letters (alleles) or either of them is `Z/Z` or `-/-`.
2. I will compare columns from lines `1` through `5` with `P2` across columns `XY1` to `XY5`. If they match the output shoulod contain `1` otherwise `0`. I continue this my program encounters second set of `P1` and `P2` lines.
3. I will calculate a line total for lines `1` to `5` including only the columns that differed between `P1` and `P2`.
4. I will calculate a line percentage for lines `1` to `5` by dividing the sum by the number of columns that differed between `P1` and `P2`.

I am expecting output like this

```
LINES XY1  XY2  XY3  XY4  XY5       
P1    eq   nq   eq   eq   eq   SUM  %
P2                                  1   
1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0
2     0    1    0    0    1    1    100
3     0    0    0    0    1    0    0
4     1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5     1    1    0    0    0    1    100
```

I have data in more than 5,000 rows, and at present I am working in Excel 2010 with different formulae but it is taking lot of my energy.

I would like to do this Perl but I am a newbie in Perl. I have succeeded in reading the file onto the screen.

Here is the code I written up to the file reading part.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'csv.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

open(CSV, "<", $file) or die $!;

while (<CSV>) {
  if ($csv->parse($_)) {
    my @columns = $csv->fields();
    print "@columns\n";
  }
  else {
    my $err = $csv->error_input;
    print "Failed to parse line: $err";
  }
}

close CSV;
```

Comment: Wow, this is a tall order. You haven't even said if your data is tab-delimited or not. You used the default comma delimiter of `Text::CSV`.

Answer (score 2):

This program appears to do what you need. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line. The generated output is sent to `STDOUT`.

Many people don't believe me, but it's *wrong* to use `Text::CSV` to parse tab-separated data. It needs the separator character setting up, and quoting and escaping options disabled and, if done right, it ends up behaving *identically* to `split /\t/`. You don't say whether your data is tab-separated or just whitespace-separated, but since you appear to have no data that contains whitespace I have assumed the latter. This sort of data is parsed very simply by using just `split`.

It works by checking each line of the input to see whether it is a `P1` line, a `P2` line, a numbered line or anything else (assumed to be a header line).

- When a header line is encountered, the `printf` format for subsequent lines is derived from the spacing of the header fields, and the line is copied to the output
- When a `P1` line is encountered, the data is simply saved in `@p1`
- When a `P2` line is encountered, the data is saved in `@p2` for comparison to subsequent data. Appropriate `P1` and `P2` lines are printed to the output, and an array `@unequal` is calculated that contains the indices of the columns for which the `P1` data doesn't match the `P2` data
- A numbered data line is compared column by column with the data saved in `@p2`, and `1` or `0` is inserted accordingly into the corresponding output column. The value of `$sum` is calculated by adding together the values of the output columns listed in the `@unequal` array. The percentage is calculated by dividing by the number of entries in `@unequal`, and the data is printed to the output.

**Note**

It's unclear how the *"second set of P1 and P2."* starts, so this code may not handle it properly. You also don't say how you want fractional percentages displaying, so this code just prints stuff like `33.3333333333333`.

Also, you don't say what the `1` at the end of the output `P2` lines indicates, so I have simply copied it literally.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub compare_alleles {
  return 1 if grep {$_ eq '-/-' or $_ eq 'Z/Z' } @_;
  return $_[0] eq $_[1] ? 1 : 0;
}

my $format;
my (@p1, @p2);
my @unequal;

while (<>) {

  unless (/^(P?\d)/) {
    my @widths;
    push @widths, $+[1] - $-[1] while /(\S+\s*)/g;
    pop @widths;
    push @widths, $widths[-1], $widths[-1];
    $format = join '', map("%-${_}s", @widths, ''), "\n";
    print;
    next;
  }

  my @fields = split;

  if ($fields[0] eq 'P1') {
    @p1 = @fields;
  }
  elsif ($fields[0] eq 'P2') {
    @p2 = @fields;
    printf $format, 'P1', map (compare_alleles($p1[$_], $p2[$_]) ? 'eq' : 'nq', 1..5), 'SUM', '%';
    printf $format, 'P2', map('', 1..5), '', '1';
    @unequal = grep { not compare_alleles($p1[$_], $p2[$_]) } 1..5;
  }
  else {
    my @columns = ($fields[0], map { $fields[$_] eq $p2[$_] ? 1 : 0 } 1..5);
    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $_ for @columns[@unequal];
    my $percent = $sum == 0 ? 0 : $sum * 100 / @unequal;
    printf $format, @columns, $sum, $percent;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
LINES XY1  XY2  XY3  XY4  XY5
P1    eq   nq   eq   eq   eq   SUM  %
P2                                  1
1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0
2     0    1    0    0    1    1    100
3     0    0    0    0    1    0    0
4     1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5     1    1    0    0    0    1    100
```

Comment: Dear borodin thanks lot for your help. please ignore that 1 that is sum of NQ between P1 and P2 that i used in % calculation. My data in excel looks like My header line (lines, XY1 to XY5 (this is same for all the sets) followed by row with P1 (parent1) and P2 (parent2), followed by rows with lines (off-springs) like this sequence 2nd set will continue like this with their results for XY1 to XY5 (these XY number may change some time). I want to express % upto 4 digits like 89.94. I am getting error like use of unintialized vlaue $_ in concatenation at line19 after using your code. Thankslot

Comment: Can you put a pastebin up? I need to see the exact file contents if you can't fix this yourself. Please also show what output you would like for multiple data sets.

Comment: @user2134713: Please don't try to extend your question by editing my answer. You can either add small amounts of data to your question, or create a page on [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and link to it.

Comment: Dear Borodin, thank you for your reply and this is the link for pastebin http://pastebin.com/FDh9GQVg. I given sample data of three parent sets and i did expected results for first set. Hope i explained you well. Thank you