# Need to extract value from a file and subtract from variable in Perl

Tags: perl, awk

FILE:

```
1,2015-08-20,00:00:00,89,1007.48,295.551,296.66,

2,2015-08-20,03:00:00,85,1006.49,295.947,296.99,

3,2015-08-20,06:00:00,86,1006.05,295.05,296.02,

4,2015-08-20,09:00:00,85,1005.87,296.026,296.93,

5,2015-08-20,12:00:00,77,1004.96,298.034,298.87
```

code:

```
 use IPC::System::Simple qw( capture capturex );
 use POSIX;

 my $tb1_file = '/var/egridmanage_pl/daily_pl/egrid-csv/test.csv';
 open my $fh1, '<', $tb1_file or die qq{Unable to open "$tb1_file" for input: $!};

 my @t1_temp_12 = map {
        chomp;
        my @t1_ft_12 = split /,/;
        sprintf "%.0f", $t1_ft_12[6] if $t1_ft_12[2] eq '12:00:00';
 } <$fh1>;

 print "TEMP @t1_temp_12\n";

 my $result = @t1_temp_12 - 273.14;

 print "$result should equal something closer to 24 ";
```

`$result` value prints out `-265.14`  making me think the `@t1_temp_12` is hashed

So I tried to do awk

```
     my $12temp = capture("awk -F"," '$3 == "12:00:00" {print $7 - 273-.15}' test.csv");
```

I've tried using ``, qx, open, system all having the same error result using the awk command

But this errors out.  When executing awk at command line i get the favoured results.

Comment: Can anyone explain why we get so many `how do I call awk from perl` questions? Perl can do anything that awk can do, right? So what's the point of calling awk from perl???

Comment: You really want to look into using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) for parsing CSV files.

Comment: Not hashed - `@array` in a scalar context returns the number of elements.

Comment: When you post a question on Stack Overflow, please copy and paste the exact code you're using instead of typing it into the Ask box. `my $result = "@t1_temp_12 - 273.14";` would not set `$result` to -265.14 because you're interpolating an array in a string literal; you would get something more like `foo bar baz - 273.14` for an array containing `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. I'm guessing your actual code is `$result = @t1_temp_12 - 273.14;`, without the quotes.

Comment: @MattJacob: `Text::CSV` is invaluable for processing CSV files where the fields can be quoted and also contain quotes, but when the data consists strictly of unquoted fields that contain no commas then `chomp; split /,/;` is fine. It's actually very difficult to persuade the module to behave correctly for this trivial case

Comment: @Borodin What do you mean by "It's actually very difficult to persuade the module to behave correctly for this trivial case"? I've never had trouble, even with unquoted fields, using the default options to `Text::CSV->new` (although I agree that `split` is certainly simpler). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I forget exactly, but try getting it to parse `","",""","""",","`

Comment: @Borodin Yuck, unquoted fields that contain quote chars. `Text::CSV->new({ quote_char => undef, escape_char => undef })` takes care of that, but I see what you mean, `split` is easier.

Comment: The actual code has a number of print and comments so I cut and pasted the relevant stuff. I did type the 'my $result' because I accidentally removed it and put in the quotes accidentally.  Regard the AWK I did attempt the Perl code but due to not getting the results I was expecting I attempted AWK.  I dont understand the foo explanation.  I will however use the Text:CSV module.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I think I'm remembering processing a tab-separated file. Such files exist primarily so that you can put any text you like in the data, but don't allow for embedded tabs at all. To get `Text::CSV` to handle that requires the two options you mention as well as `sep_char => "\t"`, when what you really should be doing is `chomp; split /\t/;`. There are some people who consider `Text::CSV` to be a panacea and would not accept that it is nothing but a disadvantage when it comes to tab-separated data. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934965/622310) is my original rant

Comment: I think I've been irritated by `Text::CSV` inserting quotes when I didn't want them.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like there's some cargo cult programming going on here. It *looks* like all you're trying to do is find the line for `12:00:00` and print the temperature in degrees C rather than K.

Which can be done like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    print $fields[6] - 273.15 if $fields[2] eq "12:00:00";
}

__DATA__
1,2015-08-20,00:00:00,89,1007.48,295.551,296.66,
2,2015-08-20,03:00:00,85,1006.49,295.947,296.99,
3,2015-08-20,06:00:00,86,1006.05,295.05,296.02,
4,2015-08-20,09:00:00,85,1005.87,296.026,296.93,
5,2015-08-20,12:00:00,77,1004.96,298.034,298.87
```

Prints:

```
25.72
```

You don't really need to do `map` `sprintf` etc. (Although you could do a `printf` on that output if you do want to format it).

Edit: From the comments, it seems one of the sources of confusion is extracting an element from an array. An array is zero or more scalar elements - you can't just assign one to the other, because .... well, what should happen if there isn't just one element (which is the usual case).

Given an array, we can:

- `pop @array` will return the last element (and remove it from the array) so you could `my $result = pop @array;`
- `[0]` is the first element of the array, so we can `my $result = $array[0];`
- Or we can assign one array to another: `my ( $result ) = @array;` - because on the left hand side we have an array now, and it's a single element - the first element of `@array` goes into `$result`. (The rest isn't used in this scenario - but you could do `my ( $result, @anything_else ) = @array;`

So in your example - if what you're trying to do is retrieve a value matching a criteria - the normal tool for the job would be `grep` - which filters an array by applying a conditional test to each element.

So:

```
my @lines = grep { (split /,/)[2] eq "12:00:00" } <DATA>;
print "@lines";
print $lines[0];
```

Which we can reduce to:

```
my ( $firstresult ) = grep { (split /,/)[2] eq "12:00:00" } <DATA>;
print $firstresult;
```

But as we want to want to transform our array - `map` is the tool for the job.

```
my ( $result ) = map { (split /,/)[6] - 273.15 } grep { (split /,/)[2] eq "12:00:00" } <DATA>;
print $result;
```

First we:

- use grep to extract the matching elements. (one in this case, but doesn't necessarily have to be!)
- use map to transform the list, so that that we turn each element into just it's 6th field, and subtract 273.15
- assign the whole lot to a list containing a single element - in effect just taking the first result, and throwing the rest away.

But personally, I think that's getting a bit complicated and may be hard to understand - and would suggest instead:

```
my $result;
while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    if ( $fields[2] eq "12:00:00" ) {
        $result = $fields[6] - 273.15;
        last;
    }
}

print $result;
```

Iterate your data, split - and test - each line, and when you find one that matches the criteria - set `$result` and bail out of the loop.

Comment: Though the suggestions work for print I want the value to converted a variable giving me the ability to do addition math with or move into a database. Extracting the specific value from an array into a sting  $result = @t1_temp_12 ( specific 298.034 as per 12:00:00) this part is killing me.

Comment: Easiest way to do that is stick brackets around it. my ($result) = @t1_temp_12; this will put the first element of the array into $result. Alternatively use pop or $t1_temp_12[0]

Comment: @BrianB please see edits - hopefully that'll clarify further?

Answer (score 3):

`@t1_temp_12` is an array. Why are you trying to subtract an single value from it?

```
my $result = "@t1_temp_12 - 273.14";
```

Did you want to do this instead?

```
@t1_temp_12 = map {$_ - 273.14} @t1_temp_12;
```

As a shell one-liner, you could write your entire script as:

```
perl -F, -lanE 'say $F[6]-273.14 if $F[2] eq "12:00:00"' <<DATA
1,2015-08-20,00:00:00,89,1007.48,295.551,296.66,
2,2015-08-20,03:00:00,85,1006.49,295.947,296.99,
3,2015-08-20,06:00:00,86,1006.05,295.05,296.02,
4,2015-08-20,09:00:00,85,1005.87,296.026,296.93,
5,2015-08-20,12:00:00,77,1004.96,298.034,298.87
DATA
```

```
25.73
```

Comment: Not only are they trying to subtract a single value from an array, they're trying to do it inside a string literal!